# Python template engines with dummy placeholders

Tags: python, templates, properties, ini

I have very small python experience. Though I think my task can easily be solved on it.

We have big project with dozens complicated but pretty static-structured config files in xml. Also, we have some few Java-styled 'properties' files where parameters for those config templates stored. Current config templates implementation is pretty monstrous and we are about to reimplement it.

I've [seen](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating) this long templates list sheet, but can't decide which one fits my requirements best.

To be more concrete, property files have a lot of options with dot-separated keys like this:

```
# SOAP
url.ws.CustomerInfo12=http://some.soap.url.goes.here
url.ws.SWIFTCodeInfo=http://yet.another.soap.hell.from.there

# database
db.primary.url=db.oracle.thin@blah_blah:1521/ANDSOONE
db.primary.login=admin
db.primary.password=passw0rd
```

And so one. Yes, each dot-separated nesting level of property keys can be represented as an object, but **that's not how I expect template engine to understand me**. I expect it to understand me if I give him template like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<common-config>
    <primary_db>${db.primary.url}</primary_db>
</common-config>
```

and it don't try to be smarter than me and ask 'db' and 'primary' to be objects. I hope my message is clear enough. Could you please tell me if someone used any template engine for such purpose in same manner? Also, tried "Cheetah" and "quik", failed with both with specified requirements.

Thank you for advising.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not aware of any. Possibly a more pragmatic (albeit inelegant) approach would be to wrap the config in something that will allow dotted access.

Comment: Current implementation is monstrous exactly because it contains wrappers due to same reason. It replaces all configs and properties with temporary ones, changing dots to underscores, then processes it to final result. Would be great to skip this step.